# Algorithm to produce polygon triangulation with fixed inner edges?

Tags: algorithm, polygon, mesh, triangulation

I have two set of edges data, one are outer edges (form a closed path or a polygon), another is inner edges inside the polygon (not holes).

I want to generate triangular mesh from the following data such that the defined inner edges and vertices are present after mesh generation.

[image]

Comment: Can you just treat it as 2 separate polygons and triangulate them separately?

Comment: I have a set of inner and outer edges, I don't know how to produce separate polygon from that information. There may be infinite inner edges, and some inner edges vertices start from the midpoint between outer edges vertices.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [CGAL library](http:///www.cgal.org) provides a [constrained Delaunay triangulation](http://doc.cgal.org/latest/Triangulation_2/index.html#title25) class that should be doing what you need. In addition, if you need to have smaller elements, you can try the [2D Meshing algorithm](http://doc.cgal.org/latest/Mesh_2/) that will split your edges while preserving their shape.

Comment: See also [poly2tri](https://code.google.com/p/poly2tri/), which finds a CDT of a planar region given its boundary.